# Can't Get Curl Enabled in PHP 7.3.9

Tags: php, apache, curl

I keep getting this error when I try to run cUrl:

```
Call to undefined function curl_init()
```

So I try to install it with these lines:

```
extension_dir = "C:\PHP7\ext"
extension=curl
```

But it never shows up in my phpinfo();

Here is from the Apache error log:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: C:\\PHP7\\ext\\curl (The specified module could not be found.), C:\\PHP7\\ext\\php_curl.dll (The specified procedure could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
```

And I've also tried the absolute path to curl (extension=C:\PHP7\ext\php_curl.dll)

Comment: Curl is crashing on startup. Where did you get your PHP binaries from?

Comment: Downloaded them from the PHP Windows Downloads page

Comment: Restart server if you doing all .

Comment: Restart server if you doest the all ... It wil work

Comment: May I suggest you upgrade Apache to the most recent build? I had [this same problem](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78086) a few months ago and moving from httpd-2.4.29-Win64-VC15 to httpd-2.4.39-win64-VS16 (Apache Lounge builds) was the fix for me.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález That worked!  Why don't you submit it as an answer for credit?

Answer (score 2):

If:

- Your settings look correct.
- You're trying to load the right DLL for your PHP installation and not e.g. some random one you found in Google).
- Curl works just fine from command-line PHP.
- But you get this when running PHP as Apache module:

  > PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: C:\...\ext\curl (The specified module could not be found.), C:\...\ext\php_curl.dll (The specified procedure could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Then there's a chance that it gets fixed if you upgrade Apache to the latest build. (I've had that same problem [myself](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78086).)

Comment: My apache is latest though it didn't worked for me. only downgrading to PHP 7.3.1 solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

That was my problem too. I decided to upgrade my apache to **Apache version 2.4.41**

Link to binary if you install manually: https://www.apachelounge.com/download/

My php version is 7.3.9

*good luck*